Allowing microphone access from settings using permission_handler disconnecting/restarting/crashing Flutter iOS App
When the microphone access to my flutter app is permanently denied, I am accessing app settings using permission_handler: 11.3.1  package's openAppSetting() method.
There when I allow access to the microphone the device is disconnected/crashed. And coming back to the app is restarting the app.


It works while I am requesting permission or allowing it. And for Android, everything works completely fine.
In the info.plist file I have permitted the microphone
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string> To send voice text this app requires Mic's permission.</string>

In the Podfile I have added:
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          # You can remove unused permissions here
          # for more information: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
          # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
            '$(inherited)',

            ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
            'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
          ]
     end
  end
end

I tried flutter clean command and deleting podfile.lock
Here is my code:
onPressed: () {
                    PermissionManager().getMicrophonePermission().then((value) {
                      if (value.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                        PermissionManager().goToOpenSetting();
                      } else if (value.isRestricted || value.isDenied) {
                        PermissionManager()
                            .requestPermission()
                            .then((requestValue) {
                          if (requestValue.isGranted) {
                            _startRecording();
                            setState(() {
                              _isVoiceEnabled = !_isVoiceEnabled;
                            });
                          }
                        });
                      } else {
                        _startRecording();
                        setState(() {
                          _isVoiceEnabled = !_isVoiceEnabled;
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  },

The onPressed() calls functions for PermissionManager class:
class PermissionManager {
  ///
  Future<PermissionStatus> getMicrophonePermission() async {
    return await Permission.microphone.status;
  }

  
  Future<PermissionStatus> requestPermission() async {
    return await Permission.microphone.request();
  }

  ///
  Future<void> goToOpenSetting() async {
    EasyLoading.showToast(
      'Please, allow microphone permission while using the app',
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    ).then((value) async {
      await openAppSettings();
    });
  }
}

Please, kindly help me find where it is going wrong. Thanks in advance to everyone.

What is the actual question ? You dont want to app to restart after changing permissions from settings?

My app is a chat App. So, I intended to allow the user to come back from the settings and come back to the state it was before on hidden state. In Android it is possible. But, for iOS I could not achieve that.

Unfortunately, it's not possible. It's OS specific thing, I am sure that Android also will not be able to restore the app state fully. When you change the permission from settings, The OS resets the app and restart the app and we don't have any control over that.

When an iOS app's permissions are changed from the Settings app, iOS terminates the app to apply the new settings. This is standard behavior for many types of permissions, including the microphone. When the user navigates to the app's settings, changes the permission, and returns to the app, iOS will restart the app to reflect the updated permissions.
